# Update sql using bind param

Tags: php, sql

I have a sql statement to update confirm code and code in the database. I'm using bind param to bind the variables. It worked fine for my select and insert sql statements. However, it keeps giving me this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

when I tried to execute the update query. I tried to search on every forums possible but found no answers and I hope someone could maybe spot my mistake. I'm having issues with `$query1`. Both code and confirmcode are varchar and not integer.

```
$username = $_GET['username']; 
$code = $_GET['code'];
$confirmcode = "1";
$updatecode ="0"; 

$query=$con->prepare("SELECT username, code FROM customer_detail WHERE username ='$username'");
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($checkusername, $checkcode);
$query->fetch();

$query1=$con->prepare("UPDATE customer_detail SET code=?, confirmcode=? WHERE username = ?"); //error
$query1->bind_param('sss',$username, $updatecode, $confirmcode); //error
$query1->execute();
```

Comment: your first query is failing; you've nothing to bind.

Comment: thanks for your response. im actually having problems with the 2nd query, the first query is working fine

Comment: Do a `echo $query1->error;` and see what it spits out. That being said, you try to use prepared statements on the first query, but you don't actually bind the variable with a placeholder, so you're vulnerable as always.

Comment: Also it seems to me, that you are setting improper variables. Arent you sending $username to code?

Comment: All im getting is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\BeautyStyle1\verifyaccount.php:42 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\BeautyStyle1\verifyaccount.php on line 42. I did everything the other forums has recommended like removing quotes but it still isn't working

Comment: @PavelJanicek I moved the $username to the back after $confirmcode and it still isn't working

Comment: That's because the script is dying before it can reach anything. After your `prepare()`, add `echo $query1->error; exit;` and see what error the query is having.

Comment: @Qirel thanks, I have this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\BeautyStyle1\verifyaccount.php on line 41

Comment: What about `$con->error;` then? It actually makes sense that you won't get much from `$query1`, because if the prepare failed, it'll be `false` :p

Comment: @Qirel i did a echo on $code and it's gives me the a value of '91f82d12' which is the value i gotten after generating a rand num and hashing it through md5. Nothing wrong with $code either

Comment: ok, you're binding these 2 variables `$query->bind_result($checkusername, $checkcode);` yet you're using 2 different ones in `('sss',$username, $updatecode, $confirmcode)` and have included a 3rd one. Are you trying to check the 2nd query with the binded results?

Comment: @Qirel It gives this error now: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: @Fred-ii- the 1st query is used to check the email verification using the user's username and password by comparing it with the $_GET['username'] and $_GET['code'] values and the 2nd query is used to update into the customer_detail table.

Comment: Ah, an actual error-message we can work with, hurray! Sounds simple enough, just close the first statement before you prepare the other. `$query->close();` - think that should do it.

Comment: And like I said, the first query isn't protected against SQL injection, even if you prepare the query - because the variable isn't bound, it's directly in the query.

Comment: @qirel thanks, it worked now. I didn't know I had to close the statement first.

Comment: someone "dropped" code down there (the longer answer); which is basically what I said at the very beginning of the question. [*"your first query is failing; you've nothing to bind. – Fred -ii- 28 mins ago"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031067/update-sql-using-bind-param#comment71236605_42031067)

Comment: @Qirel oh, i thought the prepare statement itself is a form of protection of sql injection becus that's what my lecturer taught me. Am i supposed to use '?' in the query statement?

Comment: No, using `prepare()` alone isn't enough - you have to use placeholders `?` for the query to be proteced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MySQLi can't run multiple queries at once, because it uses ubuffered queries. You'll need to close the first statement before you can run another. Add the following line after `$query->fetch();`.

```
$query->close();
```

---

This being said, your first query isn't guarded against SQL injection, because you use the variable directly in the query. Adding proper placeholders for your query, the final code would look like this

```
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT username, code FROM customer_detail WHERE username =?");
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($checkusername, $checkcode);
$query->fetch();
$query->close();

$query1 = $con->prepare("UPDATE customer_detail SET code=?, confirmcode=? WHERE username = ?");
$query1->bind_param('sss',$username, $updatecode, $confirmcode); 
$query1->execute();
$query1->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code. Basically, you need to bind the params in the same order in which the placeholders (?) appear in the sql.

```
$query=$con->prepare("SELECT username, code FROM customer_detail WHERE username = ?");
$query->bind_param('s', $username);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($checkusername, $checkcode);
$query->fetch();


$query1=$con->prepare("UPDATE customer_detail SET code=?, confirmcode=? WHERE username = ?");
$query1->bind_param('sss', $updatecode, $confirmcode, $username);
$query1->execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried tis?

```
$query1->bind_param('iis', $updatecode, $confirmcode, $username);
```